# Spark 3 stream job fails with Cannot run program "chmod"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes

Spark 3.0 on Kubernetes reading data from Kafka and pushing data out using via 3rd party Segment IO REST API.

I am facing below error while running an Spark stream job

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": error=11, Resource temporarily unavailable
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:938)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:901)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1213)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1307)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1289)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:865)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:252)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:232)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:331)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:320)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:351)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.primitiveCreate(FileSystem.java:1228)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.createInternal(DelegateToFileSystem.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFs$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFs.java:353)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFs.createInternal(ChecksumFs.java:400)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.create(AbstractFileSystem.java:605)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$3.next(FileContext.java:696)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$3.next(FileContext.java:692)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.create(FileContext.java:698)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileContextBasedCheckpointFileManager.createTempFile(CheckpointFileManager.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CheckpointFileManager$RenameBasedFSDataOutputStream.<init>(CheckpointFileManager.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CheckpointFileManager$RenameBasedFSDataOutputStream.<init>(CheckpointFileManager.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileContextBasedCheckpointFileManager.createAtomic(CheckpointFileManager.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.writeBatchToFile(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.$anonfun$add$3(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:120)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.add(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:588)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.withProgressLocked(MicroBatchExecution.scala:598)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:585)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:223)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:191)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:334)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=11, Resource temporarily unavailable
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH Environment Variable.
(Maybe you override it to add some spark/kafka jars to path?)